# Cordova - Android, push notifications to lock screen?

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification

i'm working on an app that sends push notifications to users... nothing special about that.

Special is, that my client wishes that the push notifications will be sent to the lock screen, and not only to the status bar.

I know it's a feature of Lollipop 5.0, but I have a friend with an old 4.2 Android and he receives the push notifications from the app to the lock screen somehow.

I heard it could have something to do with the `androidManifest.xml` file with notifications permissions and Android's window manager, but I haven't found nothing on it.

I'll appreciate any assistance or words of advice regarding it, maybe there's a way for Cordova to enable it, or maybe I don't understand Android developing well enough...

Much thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a friend with an old 4.2 Android and he receives the push notifications from the app to the lock screen somehow

Either he has a custom ROM installed that offers lockscreen notifications, or the device manufacturer itself implemented some equivalent of lockscreen notifications. There is no means for you, as an app developer, to put notifications on the lockscreen prior to Android 5.0.

You *can* implement a lockscreen app widget (in Java, probably not via Cordova) and display information that way, and that will work on 4.2 through 4.4.

Comment: Thanks I thought about the option that his device might have a custom ROM... and thanks for making sense about the rest, much appreciated and well explained. :) Hopefully there would be some development for that in Cordova as well in the future...

Comment: Do you know whether it's possible to send lockscreen notifications to Android 5.0 via Cordova perhaps?

Comment: @Shay: From an Android standpoint, it's automatic for normal (non-secret) notifications. So, if there is a Cordova plugin that offers standard Android `Notification` support, you should get lockscreen notifications "for free".

Comment: Much thanks, I have seen that the major Cordova plugin for push notifications got deprecated, so perhaps the new one will work! Thanks again